# how to write a MVC like .htaccess rule?

Tags: .htaccess

my goal is to write .htaccess rule "mvc like"

/param1/param2/param3/../paramN -> index.php?param1&param2&param3&...paramN

Excluding for 
/css /img /js

ex:

```
mysite.com/login/john/white->mysite.com/index.php?login&john&white
mysite.com/css/style.css -> mysite.com/css/style.css (NO RULE APPLIED)
mysite.com/img/mypic.jpg -> mysite.com/img/mypic.jpg (NO RULE APPLIED)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rewrite the URL and not css, js, img files,

Then you can use this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILNAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILNAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://example.com/index.php?$1&$2&$3 [QSA,L]
```

Which will rewrite this example URL.

```
example.com/index.php?login&john&white
```

Note that there are no key/value pairs in your query string so that might not come out as you might expect.

You can add aditional rules for longer or shorter URL's.